# Basis for a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the basis for the subspace of $\mathbb R^4$: $(w,x,y,z)$ such that  $x + y + z = 0$.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the equation?

Comment: Since you have one equation and 4 variables, the solution space should be 3 dimensional. A three dimensional solution space can be written as the span of 3 basis vectors.

Comment: I just try for 3 Dimensional. but Honestly I can't do it for 4 Dimensional :(

Comment: z = - x - y and you have a fourth variable w that is free. It appears that x and y are free but that z is determined from x and y. Best of luck.

Comment: @Tucker, Is it true $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,-1)$,$(0,0,1,-1)$

Comment: @mostafa8026 Are your ordered tuples (w,x,y,z)?

Comment: What are $x,y,z$? Are they the coordinates? Or are they the vectors? Please clarify.

Comment: @Tucker, yes (w,x,y,z).

Comment: That is a basis for the solution space @mostafa8026! Good work.

Comment: @Tucker, Thank you. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have one equation and 4 variables, the solution space should be 3 dimensional. A three dimensional solution space can be written as the span of 3 basis vectors.

$z = - x - y$ and we have a fourth variable $w$ that is free. It appears that $x$ and $y$ are free but that $z$ is determined from $x$ and $y$. Best of luck.

$$w(1,0,0,0) + x(0,1,0,-1) + y(0,0,1,-1)$$

So the basis for the solution space is:

$$(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,-1),(0,0,1,-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

First, we are going to calculate the dimension of the subspace generated by $x+y+z = 0$. 
$$dim(P) = \#variables - rank\ of\ the \ system = 4 - 1 = 3 \Rightarrow \text{The base has 3 elements.
}$$

Now you have 3 free variables so you only need to solve the equation with "trivial values"

For example, you can choose as free variables $$(y, z, t) \ y,z,t \in \mathbb{R}$$

Now we take $(1, 0, 0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ as $(y, z, t)$  to solve the equation. (Note that this values are linearly independent).

Case $(1, 0, 0)$: $x = -1 \Rightarrow (-1,1,0,0) \in P$

Case $(0, 1, 0)$: $x = -1\Rightarrow (-1,0,1,0) \in P$

Case $(0, 0, 1)$: $x = 0\Rightarrow (0,0,0,1) \in P$

$\{(-1,1,0,0), (-1,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1) \}$ is a base of the subspace $P$ of  $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: what do you mean by `range of the system`? you mean number of equation, right?

Comment: I wrote it bad, sorry I wanted to say rank.